# Item Icon not visible on ActionBar

Tags: android

The Item Icon is not displayed on the ActionBar. Even the "Action Overflow" is not displayed(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). The following code was developed on Android Studio.

**main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.suprabhatam.alarm.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:orderInCategory="0"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/share_black_48_48"
        android:title="Share" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Does the build configuration has any compatibility issues with the sdk versions ?.

Comment: did you call setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onCreate?

Comment: It looks like the method setHasOptionsMenu(true) is from Fragment class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html. But i am not using Fragment class anywhere in my code

Comment: What theme and what activity are you using?

Comment: Action overflow is only available in API17 and up

Answer (score 0):

please paste complete code. are you use : `xmlns:android`?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/share_black_48_48"
    android:title="Share">
</item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `return true;` with `return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` in onCreateOptionsMenu

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem .

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

should be replaced with

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```